# MySQL and PHP Date and Time Cheat Sheet

Tags: php, mysql

I'm confused about the choices for date and time in a MySQL database. Is there a cheat sheet that gives me the basics and summarizes the choices?

I welcome technical corrections but keep in mind this is not meant to be a reference. It's a summary cheat sheet.

Answer (score 2):

## MYSQL DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP Cheat Sheet

**DATE**
Supports range from  '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
Stored as string in YYY-MM-DD format.

**DATETIME**
Supports range from ‘1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.
Stored as a string in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

Represents a date on a calendar, and a time on wall clock. It never changes when a record is created or updated.. It never changes based on the timezone of the server. Can do dates from year 1000 to 9999.

**TIMESTAMP**
Supports range from '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC
Can’t do dates earlier than 1970, so can’t be used for birthdates.
Stored as a string in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format.

Timestamp is a distinct point in time. In MySQL it’s generally used to track changes to records, and can be set to update automatically when a record is created and/or updated.

MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values based the server’s timezone. It gets converted to UTC (coordinated universal time) for storage, and back again to the server’s time zone for retrieval.

**UNIX TIMESTAMP**
UTC adjusted number of seconds since 1/1/1970, stored as a signed 32-bit integer.

When a leap second occurs, so that the UTC day is not exactly 86400 seconds long, a discontinuity occurs in the Unix time number.

These are stored in “integer” columns in MySQL, which are stored as 32 bit internally.

**MySQL DATE FUNCTIONS**
MySQL date and time formats are strings, not integers.

FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) formats a unix timestamp as a string
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mysqldate) converts MySQL string to unix timestamp

**PHP DATE FUNCTIONS**
Php date functions work with unix timestamp, ie integers.

*string* date(*string* $format, *int* $timestamp) returns a MySQL string from a unix timestamp
*int* strtotime(*string* $mysqldate) returns a unix timestamp from an MySQL string

**WAYS TO DEAL WITH INCOMPATIBLE DATE TIME FORMATS:**
PHP converts unix timestamp to MySQL string:

```
     $mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $timestamp );
```

PHP converts MySQL string to unix timestamp:

```
     $timestamp = strtotime( $mysqldate );
```

MySQL converts unix timestamp to MySQL string:

```
    $query = "UPDATE table SET mysqldatetimefield = FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp);
```

MySQL converts MySQL string to unix timestamp:

```
    $query = "SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(mysqldate) FROM table;
```

Store unix timestamps in MySQL integer column:

```
    mysql> CREATE TABLE table ( timestamp INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (timestamp) );
    mysql> INSERT INTO table(timestamp) VALUES (1358402400)
```

Comment: It's a nice summary.  I'm not sure what you mean by "Stored as a string in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format", but DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP are not stored internally as strings. They use 3, 8, and 4 bytes respectively.